# FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen not showing notification

Tags: flutter, firebase

why my firebase not showing notification in Foreground/on application open but printing all those inside the func.

I have this on main.dart inside main()

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
    }
    FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);
  });
```

on debug console

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 4139): broadcast received for message
I/flutter ( 4139): Got a message whilst in the foreground!
I/flutter ( 4139): Message data: {}
I/flutter ( 4139): Message also contained a notification: Instance of 'RemoteNotification'
2
W/FirebaseMessaging( 4139): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use package like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications or something else to show your notification on screen. Here is a simple example of flutter_local_notifications on your onListen method.

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
print('Message data: ${message.data}');

if (message.notification != null) {
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
          ),
          iOS: const IOSNotificationDetails()),
    );
  print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
}
FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

A visible notification is not shown by default when an application is in foreground. It is up to the application to handle a message as in most cases it doesn't make sense to show a notification as a user is already using the application.

See [Foreground and Notification messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#foreground_and_notification_messages) for details.